# PySpark - Change Long type to Array type(Long type)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame read from CSV as below,

```
df1=
category    value   Referece value
count           1        1
n_timer         20      40,20
frames          54      56
timer           8       3,6,7
pdf             99      100,101,22
zip             10      10,11,12
```

but it read the columns as long type and string type, but I want both in array type(LongType) so that I can intersect these columns and get output.

I want to read the dataframe as like below:

```
category    value   Referece value

count       [1]      [1]
n_timer     [20]    [40,20]
frames      [54]    [56]
timer       [8]     [3,6,7]
pdf         [99]    [100,101,22]
zip         [10]    [10,11,12]
```

Please suggest some solution

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
# check below code
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import split 
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
df1 = sc.parallelize([("count","1","1"), ("n_timer","20","40,20"), ("frames","54","56"),("timer","8","3,6,7"),("pdf","99","100,101,22"),("zip","10","10,11,12")]).toDF(["category", "value","Reference_value"])
print(df1.show())
df1=df1.withColumn("Reference_value", split("Reference_value", ",\s*").cast("array<long>"))
df1=df1.withColumn("value", split("value", ",\s*").cast("array<long>"))
print(df1.show())

 Input df1=
+--------+-----+---------------+
|category|value|Reference_value|
+--------+-----+---------------+
|   count|    1|              1|
| n_timer|   20|          40,20|
|  frames|   54|             56|
|   timer|    8|          3,6,7|
|     pdf|   99|     100,101,22|
|     zip|   10|       10,11,12|
+--------+-----+---------------+

output df2=
+--------+-----+---------------+
|category|value|Reference_value|
+--------+-----+---------------+
|   count|  [1]|            [1]|
| n_timer| [20]|       [40, 20]|
|  frames| [54]|           [56]|
|   timer|  [8]|      [3, 6, 7]|
|     pdf| [99]| [100, 101, 22]|
|     zip| [10]|   [10, 11, 12]|
+--------+-----+---------------+
```

Answer (score -2):

Write a encoder class with value and reference column as array type..

How to do in JAVA : 
Dataset sampleDim = sqlContext.read().csv(filePath).as(Encoders.bean(sample.class));

You can try the same way in Python